# Turn off clustering with Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I am creating clusters on the map like this:

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

Without 'refreshing' the map markers, is it possible to temporarily turn off clustering and then turn it back on again?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to set maxZoom and gridSize to something minimal.

```
markerClusterer.setMaxZoom(1);
markerClusterer.setGridSize(1);
markerClusterer.redraw();
```

Before doing that you may just save previous values (getMaxZoom() and getGridSize()). Relying on [reference](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html) there are nothing like enableClustering().

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - I actually found the a good example at....http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_markerclusterer_unclusterB.html

Answer (score 3):

This `repaint()` method worked for me:

```
    var markerCluster2 = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);

$('#turnoff_clustering').click(function(){
                markerCluster2.setMaxZoom(1);
                markerCluster2.repaint();
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that in the example above MarkerClustererPlus must be used as MarkerClusterer has not .repaint() method.